# ¿Cómo agregar el ultimo objeto de mi array a un nuevo array?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando separar esta función del return, para colocar mensajes correspondientes como *ya se ingresó el elemento* y *el elemento se ingreso correctamente*.

Cabe destacar que esta función funciona, pero quiero añadir mensajes al usuario para que el entienda lo que esta sucediendo.

Este es el código original y funciona:

```
let sinRepetidos = carrito.filter((valorActual, indiceActual, arreglo) => {
  return arreglo.findIndex(valorDelArreglo =>
    JSON.stringify(valorDelArreglo) ===
    JSON.stringify(valorActual)) === indiceActual
});
console.log("Sin repetidos es:", sinRepetidos);
```

Este es el modificado:

```
let sinRepetidos = carrito.filter((valorActual, indiceActual, arreglo) => {
  return arreglo.findIndex(valorDelArreglo => {
    if (JSON.stringify(valorDelArreglo) === JSON.stringify(valorActual) === indiceActual) {
      alert('se ingreso un repetido')
    } else {
      alert('se ingreso correctamente')
    }
  });
})
console.log("Sin repetidos es:", sinRepetidos);
```

var carrito=[}//esta inicialido antes de esta funcion

```
const newItem = {
  id: id,
  codigo: codigo,
  nombre: nombre,
  cantidad_disponible: cantidad_disponible,
  talla: talla,
  talla_ropa: talla_ropa

//img: itemImg,


  }
 carrito.push(newItem)
```

Hola estoy trabajando con este codigo, mi idea es pasar solo el 1er elemento a otro array

```
carrito.push(newItem)
 let nuevoArreglo = carrito;
 var variable=nuevoArreglo.unshift(nuevoArreglo.pop());
  //var elementosRemovidos = carrito.splice(0,carrito.length);

 carrito.push(newItem[0])
 console.log('este es el elemento 0'+carrito)
```

Comment: Veo que tienes un detalle en tu comparación, te dejo una versión modificada y nos cuentas como te va https://jsfiddle.net/ah7mw6cq/

Comment: @JosueVargas eso es una respuesta? Iría en las respuestas, como respuesta.

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo no, primero le doy una posible respuesta a ver si es lo que necesita o si requiere algo más.. no me gusta responder hasta estar 100% seguro :)

Comment: @JosueVargas, pero me va eliminando al momento del else, necesito que solo se añadan y no se eliminen, solo mostrar ese mensaje de ya se añadio

Comment: @JosueVargas las respuestas también se pueden editar de acuerdo a los comentarios del OP. De hecho, es más fácil entre todos construir la respuesta de esa forma

Comment: Esta bien @Alfabravo gracias por el comentario, pero prefiero dar respuestas correctas y no estar modificando, pero igual lo tomaré en cuenta :) saludos

Comment: Estaría bien que expliques cuál es el problema actual, no solamente agregar el código con el que estás teniendo problemas ahora.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si no he entendido mal tu código tu quieres introducir los elementos en un array ya estén repetidos o no, y luego quieres mostrar un mensaje por cada elemento nuevo, y otro por cada elemento repetido.
Y finalmente devolver un array de los elementos no repetidos, Te dejo aquí como lo he planteado, creo que cumple con lo que necesitas

Filtramos el array con el método .filter, si el elemento ya existe (suponiendo que va a ser un array plano"), devolvemos true para meterlo al arrayFiltrado y establecemos el mensaje, en caso contrario establecemos false y no lo guardamos en el arrayFiltrado , pero mostrando también el mensaje. Finalmente nos quedamos con un array que solo tiene los elementos únicos.

```js
let carrito = [ "naranja", "manzana", "naranja", "pera" ];

const agregarAlCarrito = (arrayElementos) => {
  let arrayFiltrado = arrayElementos.filter((elemento, index, self) => {
    if (self.indexOf(elemento) === index) {
      console.log(`Se ha ingresado correctamente: ${elemento}`);
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log(`Repetido: ${elemento}`);
      return false;
    }
  });
  console.log(arrayFiltrado);
  return arrayFiltrado;
};

let carritoSinRepetidos = agregarAlCarrito(carrito);
```

Comment: Si ya filtrarse el arreglo es innecesario pasarlo por un `Set`. Tal vez `forEach` se ajuste más a lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: Totalmente, voy a editarlo me acabo de dar cuenta , sorry!

Comment: 0
: 
cantidad_disponible
: 
" 15"
codigo
: 
"00001"
id
: 
"15"
nombre
: 
" Nike force"
talla
: 
" 36"
talla_ropa
: 
" no existen"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)

Comment: me muestra asi y se siguen repitiendo, tengo una funcion renderizar carrito donde mape dicho array de objetos , sin parametros

Comment: ¿Puedes mandarme el array o JSON que estás mandando como parámetro? Si no es un array plano debes hacer algunas modificaciones en la función que puse

Comment: const newItem = {
    id: id,
    codigo: codigo,
    nombre: nombre,
    cantidad_disponible: cantidad_disponible,
    talla: talla,
    talla_ropa: talla_ropa

    //img: itemImg,
    
    
  }
carrito.push(newItem)

Comment: es un array de objetos asociativo

Answer (score 2):

Para ingresar el if else solo tienes que reemplazar el return por una asignación a una variable temporal.

Entonces la condición del if es esa variable temporal y antes de terminar la función, devuelves el valor guardado para que el algoritmo funcione como debería.

```js
carrito = [ "naranja", "manzana", "naranja", "pera" ]

let sinRepetidos = carrito.filter((valorActual, indiceActual, arreglo) => {
   correcto = arreglo.findIndex(valorDelArreglo =>
       JSON.stringify(valorDelArreglo) === JSON.stringify(valorActual)
   ) === indiceActual;
   if (correcto)
      console.log('se ingreso correctamente', valorActual)
   else
      console.log('repetido', valorActual)
   return correcto 
})
console.log("Sin repetidos es:", sinRepetidos);
```

Comment: sabes, me sigue insertando mas elementos al arreglo ago un carrito.push(arreglo)

Comment: @Felipe ejecuta el código del filtro una vez que hayas ingresado todos los elementos. Sino usa un [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Comment: segun tengo entendido set es automatico, como mandarle mensaje al usauario